# Using a third party router (like TPlink or asus) on a 5G router without a bridged mode but with DMZ

Tags: networking, router

For my internet connection, I have subscribed to a 5G box unlimited data plan. A 5G modem router "box" TCL HH500V is provided by my ISP. Unfortunately, it heat quite a lot, and frequently drop the wifi.

There is no bridged mode option, I asked support. However, there is a DMZ option(and I can switch off most services on the modem), is there a way I could use a router on this DMZ IP and configure it so it act as the router + wifi + DNS for my network ?

Comment: How Will doing this resolve the overheating problem, all your network traffic, still goes through the device.  What problem do you solve by doing that?

Comment: it will route less, wifi, and DHCP will be disabled.

Comment: You would do better to solve the problem of this router. If it's placed for example in a closed box, it will always heat up.

Comment: @Sylario - All traffic will flow through the modem regardless of which network device your connected to if that network device is connected to the modem. Your desired will not solve your overheating problem.

Comment: A wifi 5ghz access point heat up a lot, just disabling it will reduce the heat, also it's on a desk not in a closet.

Comment: You could do it that way or alternatively using a just a wireless access point hanging off the modem's lan port.  That may eliminate the wifi drops while making the  configuration much more straightforward for both devices (no DMZ, dhcp by modem).  NB: Wifi drop outs can happen for other reasons than defective modem overheating. For example if connecting via 2.4ghz and modem is 'smart' and hunts for better channel because of poor signal quality on current channel.